# Is there a way to enable H.264 video in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, youtube, h.264, theora

I know that Mozilla has taken an ideological stance against H.264 video, but I don't agree with it.  (And I think I paid for a hardware decoder inside my graphics card anyway?)

Is there any way I can force Firefox to play H.264 videos?  Is there a hacked version that includes support for it?  A plug-in?

Chrome's extensions aren't as good as Firefox, so I'm not ready to switch, but videos run so much smoother and more efficiently without the Flash layer in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on Windows, there's a "hack" way to include IE in FF:

- http://lifehacker.com/5488607/can-i-play-html5-youtube-videos-in-firefox-right-now

Here's a plugin that converts HTML5 to Flash, enabling H264 to be played:

- http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/70028

Here's a spin off:

- http://wildfox.sourceforge.net/

but no releases yet.

**Huge note**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264#Patent_licensing - this is a patented technology and **you**, as the user, may need to pay licenses to use the product that contains H264 code in it.

Comment: "On August 26, 2010 MPEG LA announced that H.264 encoded internet video that is free to end users will never be charged for royalties."

Comment: Exactly - anybody who creates the video and makes it free will not be charged royalties, **not** users using non-licensed software to watch it. I'm not a lawyer, so you are free to interpret it however you want - I just wanted to put it on a table.

Comment: I'd gladly pay a few bucks if they can figure out a way to ask me for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[h264ify](https://github.com/erkserkserks/h264ify-firefox)** extension. (also has a [Chrome version](https://github.com/erkserkserks/h264ify))

> h264ify is a Firefox/Chrome extension that makes YouTube stream H.264
>   videos instead of VP8/VP9 videos.
>
> Try h264ify if YouTube videos stutter, take up too much CPU, eat
>   battery life, or make your laptop hot.
>
> By default, YouTube streams VP8/VP9 encoded video. However, this can
>   cause problems with less powerful machines because VP8/VP9 is not
>   typically hardware accelerated.
>
> In contrast, H.264 is commonly hardware accelerated by GPUs, which
>   usually means smoother video playback and reduced CPU usage.